# Needs to be delete the multiple files from dir using api in node js

Tags: node.js

In this we needs to delete the files from dir using API in node js. In this whatever file is received from web API request and check if file is present or not. If present then delete it from dir.

I use fs.unlink but at this way i can able to delete only single file. With same method i want to delete multiple files from dir.

Comment: Put it in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

This method will allow you to delete all the files in your directory

```
const YourDirectoryLocation = './dir/'; //change this according to your desired directory
const fs = require('fs'); // import file system module

fs.readdir(YourDirectoryLocation, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => { // Loop of files in your directory
    console.log("Delete file: "file);
   fs.unlinkSync(file);   // delete the file that has this current element in the files array as a name
  });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Comment: I guess it's improved now